# Bitlocker won't let me continue, but there is no hard drive to be bitlocked?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, bitlocker

New to me university surplus laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad). No hard drive came with it. When I tried to start up from the USB stick to install Windows on my blank hard drive, bitlocker jumped in and tried to get me to unlock the hard drive.

While I was messing around with the hard drive plugged into another computer to make sure it didn't have anything on it yet, the laptop started up without a hard drive at all, just the USB installer plugged in, and still got the blue bitlocker recovery page.

How am I getting the bitlocker recovery page with no hard drive installed? How can I get past the bitlocker recovery page so I can install windows on my blank hard drive?

Comment: If this is a university owned device - your best to contact the IT team for that university and ask for support.

Comment: Is network boot enabled? Look in BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: Network Boot is set to USB FDD

Comment: It’s very likely a BitLocker was enabled and due to that fact the information stored within the fTPM was detected. Try clearing that information within the firmware for the device.

Comment: You can skip BL recovery always and go to a command prompt. Then, launch these: "diskpart" then "list disk" - now see if there is another disk that you don't expect to be there (like Intel Optane memory).

Comment: Bernd had it. When I took it in they saw that the tiny SSD hadn't been removed as it should have been. It had a metal panel covering it, so it wasn't visible, but whoever was clearing out the hard drives should have known to get that one too.